# Batch file export from SQL - Script editing

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, bcp

I found a bat script on the internet which exports a query from SQL with a header row and into a tab delimited csv file. The script works great, however, I need the file format to be a comma separated file rather than tabular.

I have had a bit of a play around with the BCP parts of the script, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
@ECHO OFF
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Generic script for exporting data to file from SQL Server using a SQL query.
REM The resulting file will be tab separated with newline as the row delimiter.
REM A log file is generated and kept in case of an error or when in debug mode.
REM See command syntax for details.
REM
REM History:
REM 20120327    Lars Rönnbäck   CREATED
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:constants
SET myCodePage=ACP
:variables
SET theQuery=SELECT  [D-U-N-S Number], [Company Name], [Street Address Line 1], [Street         Address Line 2], [Street Address Line 3], [Street Address Line 4], Town, [County (Actual)], [Full Postcode], [Telephone Number] FROM B2B_Jan13.dbo.DATA_HQ_1_Site_Level
SET theFile=C:\B2B_Matching_Automation\Temp_Files\Sites.csv
SET theServer=localhost
SET theDebug=%~4
SET /a aRandomNumber=%random%%%1000
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-7* delims=.:/,- " %%a IN (`ECHO %DATE%_%TIME%`) DO (SET myStartTime=%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g)
SET myColumnQuery="select top 0 * into [#columns_%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%] from (%theQuery%) q; select stuff((select char(9) + c.name from tempdb.sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id order by c.column_id for XML path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1,1,'') AS Header from tempdb.sys.tables t where t.name like '#columns_%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%%%'"
SET myHeaderFile=%theFile%.%aRandomNumber%.header
SET myDataFile=%theFile%.%aRandomNumber%.data
SET myLogFile=%theFile%.%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%.log
:checks
IF "%theQuery%"=="" (
GOTO syntax
) 
IF "%theFile%"=="" (
GOTO syntax
) 
IF "%theServer%"=="" ( 
SET theServer=%COMPUTERNAME%
)
:information
ECHO Start Time:    %myStartTime%       >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO Random Number: %aRandomNumber%     >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO File:          %theFile%           >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO Server Name:   %theServer%         >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO Query:                             >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO.                                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO %theQuery%                         >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
:export
BCP %myColumnQuery% queryout "%myHeaderFile%" -T -S "%theServer%" -a 65535 -c -C %myCodePage% -q >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
BCP "%theQuery%" queryout "%myDataFile%" -T -S "%theServer%" -a 65535 -c -C %myCodePage% -q >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
ECHO.                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO Merging files...   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
ECHO.                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
COPY /A "%myHeaderFile%" + "%myDataFile%" "%theFile%" /B /Y >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
:cleanup
DEL "%myHeaderFile%" >NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
DEL "%myDataFile%" >NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
IF /I NOT [%theDebug%]==[Y] (
DEL "%myLogFile%"
)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
GOTO end
:error
ECHO 
ECHO ERROR: An export error has occured!
IF NOT [%myLogFile: =%]==[] (
  ECHO Details can be found in:
  ECHO %myLogFile%
)
ECHO 
EXIT /B 1
:syntax
    ECHO.
ECHO SYNTAX: %0 "sql query" "output file" [server] [Y]
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO You must specify an SQL query and an output file name in which the results of  
ECHO the query will be stored. Specifying a server is optional and defaults to the  
ECHO server you are executing on. If a fourth argument is given as Y a log file of
ECHO the command outputs will be saved in the same folder as the output file.
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:end
REM This is the end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the -t Option of the BCP Command.

> **-t** field_term
>
> ```
> Specifies the field terminator. The default is \t (tab character). Use this
>  parameter to override the default field terminator. For more
>  information, see Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server).
>
> If you specify the field terminator in hexadecimal notation in a bcp.exe command, 
>  the value will be truncated at 0x00. For example, if
>  you specify 0x410041, 0x41 will be used.
>
> If field_term begins with a hyphen (-) or a forward slash (/), do not include a
>   space between -t and the field_term value.
> ```

[Found Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

I've not used this myself but maybe that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've had a read through and played around a bit further with the script. The '-t,' option in BCP has correctly made the file comma delimited and ties in perfectly with the header row of the file.

Thanks for your help.